# How to extract webpage source code using Scrapy's xpath?

Tags: python, xpath, scrapy

I have written the following code

```py
from scrapy import Selector
html = '''
<html><head></head><body><table>

<tr> <td>a1</td> <td>b1</td> </tr>
<tr> <td>a2</td> <td>b2</td> </tr>

</table></body></html>
'''

selector = Selector(text=html)
temp = selector.xpath("//td").extract()
print(temp)
```

and hope to get the following result

```
[
'<td>a1</td>',
'<td>b1</td>',
'<td>a2</td>',
'<td>b2</td>'
]
```

But I actually got this

```
[
'<td>a1</td> <td>b1</td> </tr>\n<tr> <td>a2</td> <td>b2</td> </tr>\n</table>\n</body>\n</html>\n', 
'<td>b1</td> </tr>\n<tr> <td>a2</td> <td>b2</td> </tr>\n</table>\n</body>\n</html>\n', 
'<td>a2</td> <td>b2</td> </tr>\n</table>\n</body>\n</html>\n', 
'<td>b2</td> </tr>\n</table>\n</body>\n</html>\n'
]
```

---

but with '/text()' in xpath

```py
temp = selector.xpath("//td/text()").extract()
```

It turned out to be alright

```
['a1', 'b1', 'a2', 'b2']
```

---

It might just be a simple question, I just didn't find the key.

I tried 'extract', 'extract_frist', 'get', 'getall' all have the same problem.

I don't know what's wrong, please help me

Comment: This code is true

Comment: My output is different than your output with provided code. Are you sure you're not overwriting `temp` or printing something different?

Comment: there is no any error. And it gives what you want. ['<td>a1</td>', '<td>b1</td>', '<td>a2</td>', '<td>b2</td>']

Comment: What is your scrapy version

Comment: Scrapy 2.6.1, Thx all. Although I don't know why, but now I know nothing wrong with my code

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After I uninstall my Anaconda, then install a pure python, I fixed this problem...
That's strange.